# Reshaping data in R for network analysis

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, data-manipulation, network-analysis

I have a table that I need to reshaping for the network analysis.

I need to count the relationships between the different partners of the same project.

| project ID | partner 1 ID | partner 2 ID | partner 3 ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P01 | P02 | P03 |
| 2 | P02 | P04 |  |
| 3 | P01 | P03 | P04 |

To do this, I would like to create a new table from the first one detailing each relationship to get something like this and then prepare my node and edge tables.

| project ID | Relation partner to | Relation partner from |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P01 | P02 |
| 1 | P01 | P03 |
| 1 | P02 | P03 |
| 2 | P02 | P04 |
| 3 | P01 | P03 |
| 3 | P01 | P04 |
| 3 | P03 | P04 |

I have been struggling to format my data like this. I did several searches on Google, but did not find a solution to my answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

With `pivot_longer` and `combn`, get all combinations of relations per groups:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-project.ID) %>% 
  group_by(project.ID) %>% 
  do(data.frame(t(combn(.$value, 2)))) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  select(project.ID,
         `Relation partner to` = X1,
         `Relation partner from` = X2)

# A tibble: 7 × 3
# Groups:   project.ID [3]
  project.ID `Relation partner to` `Relation partner from`
       <int> <chr>                 <chr>                  
1          1 P01                   P02                    
2          1 P01                   P03                    
3          1 P02                   P03                    
4          2 P02                   P04                    
5          3 P01                   P03                    
6          3 P01                   P04                    
7          3 P03                   P04
```

data

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "'project ID'   'partner 1 ID'  'partner 2 ID'  'partner 3 ID'
1   P01 P02 P03
2   P02 P04 NA
3   P01 P03 P04")
```